# What are the requirements for the Katagelasticism achievement?

Tags: achievements, rogue-legacy

Recently, Rogue Legacy was updated to add new bosses, traits, and a new class. They also added some new steam achievements.

5 of the 6 new achievements looks like they are gotten from beating the new bosses.

How do you unlock the last one?

name -Katagelasticism 
description - Mock the traitor.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [wiki page](http://rogue-legacy.wikia.com/wiki/Special_Items)

> After completing all the upgraded versions of the bosses, you will be
>   able to get the "Traitor's Obol". After giving this Obol to Charon,
>   any boss chamber that you have previously completed will lead you to a
>   fight, where you play Johannes the Traitor with 700Hp and 300Mp, using
>   his multiple-daggers and multiple-axes spell. You will fight against
>   two copies of yourself with more HP and MP. Once you have won, you
>   will earn the achievement "Syngenesophobia" and be able to play as the
>   new class "Traitor".
>
> Using the Traitor class to enter Johannes' room will then give you the
>   achiement "Katagelasticism"

Comment: I still don't get how to find the Traitor's Obol.  Should I just "farm" the spiritual shrines after the 4 upgraded bosses have been defeated ?

Comment: I've just found it: it drops randomly at a spiritual shrine after the 4 upgraded bosses have been defeated.

Answer (score 2):

You have to unlock the new class,

> the Traitor, obtainable by beating all of the new bosses

and use it to fight and kill Johannes.

Answer (score 1):

Be the new class when fighting Johannes